Pivot Table - Calculated Field Additional Function, or Condition
Is it possible on Pivot to add an additional formula that if condition is met, it will be added on the current values on the pivot?
I have here an example
Agent Joe has multiple breaks for the day, and for each day, we only allow a single 15min break for each punches and a total of 1 hour overall duration for the breaks. So if an agent exceeded 15 min for a single punch, it will count as overbreak, and/or if an agent exceeds 1hour overall of breaks for the day.

In this pivot table, it is showing 1 count of overbreak which is the 16min duration on row 12, however, is it possible that when it exceeded 1hour duration overall for duration, it will add an additional count for overbeak in the pivot?
Desired Outcome on Overbreak is = 2 (1 count for that 16min break and 1 count for >1hour total duration of all breaks)

Not directly that I know of, but you could add a helper column where it's 1 if = "On Time" and 2 if ="Overbreak" and then use that number in your PivotTable as a sum rather than a count.  Or... PowerQuery is another option.

I can try the helper column idea first, can you give more detail about how can I get away with this using the helper column? I can go ahead and count as sum to get the number of overbreaks and on time, but how can show if an agent exceeds the 1hr treshold for the total breaks? is that possible through calculated field?

I think I might need some clarity on what you want the end game of this to actually look like and a better understanding of your starting point.  I may have misunderstood how you wanted Overbreak handled, which is why my helper column idea.  Reviewing your ask, I think a Power Query is going to be your best option.  I'm assuming you have many different names in a table and the Total Duration doesn't actually exist?  Otherwise, delete row 13 and make the 'total' row part of your PivotTable with data:  |Agent Joe|Total|=sum(C2:C12)|=if(C13>60,"Overbreak","")|
